# Keeping elasticsearch in sync with key or versioning

Tags: search, elasticsearch, lucene

So I have a situation where I get in a lot of large XML files and I want that data sycronised on elasticsearch.

**Current way**

- Have index_1
- When data is updated create blank index_2
- Load all of latest data into index_2
- Alias to index_2 and delete index_1

**Proposed way**

- Have a synced.xml file which has been sycronised with elasticsearch
- When a new timedated xml file is availiable compare against synced.xml
- If anything is new in the timedated xml file, add just that to ES
- Rename timedated xml to synced.xml

This means out of 500,000 items, I only have to add the 5,000 items that have changed for example, not duplicate the 500,000 items.

**Question**

In a scenario like this, how to I ensure they are sycronised? For example, what happens if elasticsearch gets wiped, how can I tell my program that it would need to add the whole lot again. Is there a way to use some sort of sycronisation key on elasticsearch, or perhaps a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I recommend...

1. Add a stored field to your type to store a hash like MD5
2. Use Scan/Scroll to export the ID and Hash from ES
3. In your backing dataset export ID and Hash
4. Use something like MapReduce to "join" on exported ids from each
   set
5. Where there are differences via comparing the hash or finding
   missing keys, index/update

The hash is only useful if want to detect document changes. This also assume that either you persist ES's IDs back to your backing store or that you self assign IDs.